# Odoo 13: Is it possible to use SQL query to build a new filter/search?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-13

Odoo 13: Is there a way to use SQL query to create a new filter/search with Python?

I know only one way of creating a filter:

```
<filter name="Country - USA" string="Country: USA" domain="[('country_id','=','USA')]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a contextual action to return another action based on the python code you write.